# Display the time input using Moment.js

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in my code in something easy but I can't solve it.

I am trying to subtract two times without the date, and I figured out how to do it

but I want to display the time in the input also not just the result

Here is what i want to show

```
var startTime=moment("06:51 am", "HH:mm a");
var endTime=moment("04:16 pm", "HH:mm a");
```

These are the two input I want to display. I tried the `var startTime` and `endTime` but it did not work. I want `06:51 am` and `04:16 pm` to be display

**JS code:**

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var startTime = moment("06:51 am", "HH:mm a");

    var endTime = moment("04:16 pm", "HH:mm a");
    var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
    var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
    var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;

    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML =
      hours + " hour and " + minutes + " minutes.";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.textContent` to display the time in your `div` or where you want.

Its not ideal to use `.innerHTML` - Read more why its not [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

For moment js to diplay time only use `.format` function available in `moment.js`

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var startTime = moment("06:51 am", "HH:mm a");

  var endTime = moment("04:16 pm", "HH:mm a");
  var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
  var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
  var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;

  document.getElementById("start").textContent =  'Start = ' +startTime.format('HH:mm a');
  document.getElementById("end").textContent = 'End = ' +endTime.format('h:mm a');
  document.getElementById("time").textContent = 'Difference ' +hours+ ' hour and '+ minutes+' minutes.' ;
}


myFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>


<span id="start"></span>
<br>
<span id="end"></span>

<div id="time">

</div>
```

Comment: @Aqua glad to hear. please accept as the asnwer / solution and upvote as well by following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers